# Creating a sequence on an existing table - ORA-00940: invalid ALTER command

Tags: java, sql, oracle, alter

I created a sequence and I want a table to make use of it.  The creation of the sequence works fine. However, I when I try to alter the table in order to make use of the sequence, I get this error (in `personInformationSequenceAlterTest`):

> ORA-00940: invalid ALTER command

Please note I need to use Java (Eclipse IDE).

```
    String personInformationSequenceTest = 
              "CREATE SEQUENCE seq_person "
            + "start with 1 "
            + "increment by 1 "
            + "NOCACHE "
            + "NOCYCLE ";

    String personInformationSequenceAlterTest =
              "alter table personInformationTest "
            + "alter column personId " 
            + "set default nextval('seq_person')";

    String personInformationSequenceOwnedTest = 
            "alter sequence seq_person owned by personInformationTest.personId";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your alter statement has syntax problem.

Try this (assuming datatype is int for that column. Change accordingly):

```
alter table personInformationTest modify (personId int default seq_person.nextval);
```

This will only work in Oracle 12c and up.

For 11g or lower, you can use triggers. If you don't want to use triggers, you can explicitly use `seq_person.nextval` in your inserts.

```
insert into personInformationTest (personId, . . .)
values (seq_person.nextval, . . .)
```

Comment: Im currently using 11g, is there a way not to use triggers in this case ?

Comment: The only way is to explicitly write seq_person.nextval in your insert statement then.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Check by Changing

> String personInformationSequenceAlterTest =
>                 "alter table personInformationTest "
>               + "alter column personId " 
>               + "set default nextval('seq_person')";

to

> String personInformationSequenceAlterTest =
>                 "alter table personInformationTest "
>               + "modify column personId " 
>               + "set default nextval('seq_person')";

In Oracle and MySql we use "Modify" for altering an existing column . In SQL Server / MS Access , "Alter" is used .

Comment: I tried using this but it gives me a - ORA-00936: missing expression - when i try to run it